# My external harddrive has semi dissapeared?

Tags: hard-drive

When I enter the command `lsusb` I get:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1058:1023 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements SE
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
```

My hard drive is device `006`. So it is connected through usb...

---

Then when I enter `fdisk -l` I get nothing returned.

---

When I enter `mount` I get:

```
/dev/root on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=244128k,nr_inodes=61032,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=49660k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=99300k)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

The harddrive is not to be seen!

---

When I enter `df -h` I get:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          7.2G  3.1G  3.9G  44% /
/dev/root       7.2G  3.1G  3.9G  44% /
devtmpfs        239M     0  239M   0% /dev
tmpfs            49M  288K   49M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            97M     0   97M   0% /run/shm
/dev/mmcblk0p1   56M  9.8M   47M  18% /boot
```

The harddrive is not to be seen!

---

The Harddrive was working perfectly and was mounted to `/media/usbhdd`.

Since messing arround with permissions, users and groups inside the mounted directory and also using the command:

```
dd if=/dev/sda | pv | dd of=/media/usbhdd/pibackupsda.iso bs=4M
```

And stopping it half way through! The hard drive has done this?

---

#### more info on HDD using command `sudo lsusb -v`:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1058:1023 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements SE
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1058 Western Digital Technologies, Inc.
  idProduct          0x1023 Elements SE
  bcdDevice           20.05
  iManufacturer           1 Western Digital
  iProduct                2 Elements 1023
  iSerial                 3 575948414233324647363436
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

### `sudo lsusb -t`

```
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=smsc95xx, 480M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 4, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 5, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 6, If 0, Class=stor., Driver=usb-storage, 480M
```

---

### `/sys/block/`

```
loop0  loop3  loop6    ram0   ram11  ram14  ram3  ram6  ram9
loop1  loop4  loop7    ram1   ram12  ram15  ram4  ram7  sda
loop2  loop5  mmcblk0  ram10  ram13  ram2   ram5  ram8
```

Not there.

### `dmesg | grep sda`

```
[    5.496746] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 976769024 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465 GiB)
[    5.520036] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[    5.536933] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[    5.551813] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    5.568548] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[    5.592805] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[    5.599901] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    5.966566]  sda: sda1 sda2
[    5.978879] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[    5.997075] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[    6.010198] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    6.028241] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

### ``

---

I have also restarted the device and the harddrive.

Any ideas?

Comment: Showing up in `lsusb` doesn't quite mean it's completely accessible to the system; this is the minimum required for the kernel to identify the device so it can load an appropriate driver.  If that doesn't happen, it won't show up anywhere else.  Check the `/sys/block/` directory and see if there is an entry for it there.  You should also have a look through the system logs (the default catch-all on raspbian is `/var/log/syslog`) for that time period and see if there is any clue about what happened.

Comment: It is not in system block!! And it is taking a very long time to look through the logs!!

Comment: Yeah, the logs can be pretty thick.  Actually `/var/log/kern.log` might be better as some things will be filtered out of that.  You could also try unplugging it, plugging it back in, then `dmesg | grep sda` and `dmesg | grep "1058:1023"`; one or the other of those should give some details.

Comment: please see updates in question. PS. `dmesg | grep "1058:1023"` showed up nothing

Comment: BTW: `dd if=/dev/sda` outputting back to the same device will never work out.  `dd` just copies raw blocks; it doesn't know whether they have a purpose or not.  In other words, that will copy *the entire volume of the drive*, which will obviously not then fit back onto it -- it is destined to end up full before then.  It's also going to create a totally inconsistent image since `dd` doesn't care about filesystems, and that filesystem will be changing as you copy the backup to it.  This is part of why `dd` is a **bad tool for creating filesystem back-ups**.

Comment: it was to a different device though? (The external hard drive)? Yeah I wont do this again! I have been looking through [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/132672/363167)

Comment: *"it was to a different device though?"* -> You said sda was mounted on `/media/usbhdd/` and then you copied sda to a file there, right?  So that's the same device, or rather, a partition on the same device. That shouldn't have broken the drive or done any harm beyond filling up the filesystem with a giant junk .iso though.  You should have a look at the drive on a normal laptop or something.  That dmesg output implies there might be something wrong.

Comment: Oh okay I get you sorry! I am currently 200 miles away from the pi which kinda sucks! Are there any more tests I can do?

Comment: Not that I can think of.  If it shows up in `dmesg` but not `/sys/block`, something's not working at a low level (i.e., with the kernel driver).  That could be a glitch in the driver software, but if it was working ok before, it could instead be that something's gone with the hardware.

Comment: Damn it!! I am so screwed!!! Thank you for your help!!

Comment: I was just looking at your `/sys/block/` stuff above and actually `sda` *is there*; it's the last thing.  So the device is accessible; that `sda1` and `sda2` aren't there implies the partition table is screwed up.  Try `fdisk /dev/sda`; you might end up having to reformat the drive.

Comment: WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Command (m for help):

Comment: Command action
   a   toggle a bootable flag
   b   edit bsd disklabel
   c   toggle the dos compatibility flag
   d   delete a partition
   l   list known partition types
   m   print this menu
   n   add a new partition
   o   create a new empty DOS partition table
   p   print the partition table
   q   quit without saving changes
   s   create a new empty Sun disklabel
   t   change a partition's system id
   u   change display/entry units
   v   verify the partition table
   w   write table to disk and exit
   x   extra functionality (experts only)

Comment: Partition table scan:
  MBR: hybrid
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Comment: Yeah, debian/raspbian doesn't update the tools enough; newer fdisks work with GPT.  Anyway, [gdisk](http://linux.die.net/man/8/gdisk) should be available in a package (`apt-cache search gdisk`) and that will work.  You'll at least be able to see if there are intact partitions there.  If so try and mount one.  Now I gotta go shovel snow...

Comment: Thank you very much I am pretty confused about what is happening. I perform your command `apt-cache search gdisk` which then returns `gdisk - GPT fdisk text-mode partitioning tool` then when i perform the command `sudo fdisk -l` the harddrive can be seen after the error `ARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.` When I try mount it though I get the error `mount: you must specify the filesystem type` and when I do I get the error `NTFS signature is missing.
The device '/dev/sda2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.` ?

Comment: And which way would you recommend creating filesystem back-ups ?

Comment: what do you get from running sudo blkid

Comment: I have just done this `mkfs -t ntfs /dev/sda2` and reformatted the HDD and now it is working.

Comment: Regarding the "Asking for cache data failed" and "Assuming drive cache: write through" issues, see [my recent question on this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/59628/54234).